# Finding default user.home when it has been overridden in Java VM options

Tags: java, windows, jvm, environment-variables

Let's say that I develop a plugin for a software that makes a call to -Duser.home in the JVM options.

How can I figure out the **default** user.home property of the system? For instance, on Windows, I'd like to know the "C:/Users/USERNAME" location, rather than what is overridden by the software.

Is it possible?

EDIT:
I already tried everything suggested in the supposed duplicate/original question.

```
String homeDir=System.getProperty("user.home");
```

is **not** a solution, since this value is changed by the software hosting my plugin: in fact there is a call to

```
-Duser.home="Software-forced user.home"
```

that I would like to bypass to get the real thing that looks like a user home...